# eclipse memory analyzer tool not working mac m1 java 8

Tags: eclipse, java-8, apple-m1, eclipse-memory-analyzer, ventura

Eclipse memory analyser tool doesn't work on my mac m1 ventura with oracle java 8 installed. Getting the below error while opening the app.

[image]

**Jvm shared library "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib" does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.**

Tried multiple questions asked on stackoverflow earlier but nothing seems to work anymore.
I have tried:

1. Downloading mat from browser as well as homebrew
2. added      -vm/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
   in Info.plist present at /Application/mat -> show package contents -> Info.plist
3. JAVA_HOME updated /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home

from articles like:
1.[Mac OS, JDK1.7 (and 1.8) does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589932/mac-os-jdk1-7-and-1-8-does-not-contain-the-jni-createjavavm-symbol?rq=3)

2.[Failed to locate method JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs in the libjvm.dylib (Mac OS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118750/failed-to-locate-method-jni-getcreatedjavavms-in-the-libjvm-dylib-mac-os?rq=3)

Please help me or at least suggest any good alternative to this app.

Comment: What version of Eclipse and MAT are involved? It can make a difference, you know. And why a 2 year old JDK patch release?

Comment: The architecture of Eclipse MAT and the JDK must match - both aarch64 or both x86_64. Recent versions of Eclipse require at least Java 17.

Comment: The Eclipse MAT site [here](https://eclipse.dev/mat/downloads.php) clearly says that Java 17 is the minimum version required.There are downloads there for path aarch64 and x86_64.

Comment: @greg-449 don't understand, mat is there for like decades before java 17. can't find the older versions for download

Comment: Software gets updated to use new language features. The current version of MAT (and Eclipse) require Java 17, older versions would have run with older versions of Java.